# Resolving yacc conflicts - rules useless in parser due to conflicts

Tags: c, yacc

I am working on a yacc file to parse a given file and convert it to an equivalent c++ file. I have created the following grammar based on the provided syntax diagrams:

```
program:    PROGRAMnumber id 'is' comp_stmt
            ;

comp_stmt:    BEGINnumber statement symbol ENDnumber
              ;

statement:    statement SEMInumber statement 
              | id EQnumber expression
              | PRINTnumber expression
              | declaration
              ;

declaration:    VARnumber id
                ;

expression:    term
               ;

term:    term as_op term
         | MINUSnumber term
         | factor
         ;

factor:    factor md_op factor
           | ICONSTnumber
           | id
           | RPARENnumber expression LPARENnumber
           ;

as_op:    PLUSnumber
          | MINUSnumber
          ;

md_op:    TIMESnumber
          | DIVnumber
          ;

symbol:    SEMInumber
           | COMMAnumber
           ;

id:    IDnumber
       | id symbol id
       ;
```

The only issue I have remaining is that I am receiving this error when trying to compile with yacc.

```
conflicts: 14 shift/reduce
calc.y:103.17-111.41: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts: declaration: VARnumber id
```

I have resolved the only other conflict I have encountered, but I am not sure what the resolution for this conflict is. The line it should match is of the format

```
var a, b, c, d;
```

or

```
var a;
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Also, single quotes are for single-character tokens; with bison, you can use `"var"`, but you still need a `%token` declaration to have a symbolic value you can return from your scanner.

Comment: I fixed that issue in my last edit. There was a token set up for var, I missed it initially, but even after replacing it, the error remains. What other issues do you see with my formatting, so I can fix them?

Comment: Are you really using token names like `COMMAnumber`? That verges on the unreadable... I assumed they were missing whitespace. Do you have `%left` declarations?

Comment: I'm using a lex file provided for the project. That's just what I was given to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your productions intended to derive lists are ambiguous and therefore generate reduce/reduce conflicts. For example:

```
 id: id symbol id
```

Will be clearly ambiguous when there are three identifiers: are the first two to be reduced first, or the last two? The usual list idiom is left-recursion:

```
id_list: id | id_list `,` id
```

For most languages, that would not be correct for statements, which are *terminated* with semi-colons, not *separated* by them, but that model would work for a comma-separated list of identifiers, or for a left-associative sequence of addition operators.

For statements, you probably want something more like:

```
statement_list: | statement_list statement ';'
```

Speaking of `symbol`, do you really believe that `,` and `;` have the same syntactic function? That seems unlikely, since you write `var a, b, c, d;` and not, for example, `var a; b, c; d,`.

The "useless rule" warning produced by bison is exactly because your grammar allows `id`s to be separated with semicolons. When the parser sees `"var" ID` with `;` as lookahead, it first reduces `ID` to `id` and then needs to decide whether to reduce `var id` to `declaration` or to shift the `;` in order to later reduce it to `symbol` and then proceed with the reduction of `id symbol id`. In the absence of precedence rules, bison always resolves shift/reduce conflicts in favour of shifting, so that is what it does in this case. But the result is that it is never possible to reduce `"var" id` to `declaration`, making the production useless as the result of a shift-reduce conflict resolution, which is more or less what the warning says.

Comment: My apologies. I actually resolved the issue with the statement conflict before posting this but forgot to update it in the code block. I have fixed this, but your solution seems more elegant so I may integrate that method instead. However, this doesn't address the remaining conflict I am encountering. I am more concerned at the moment with the conflict listed in the original question.

Comment: @neomang: I'm pretty sure it is a consequence of the `id` ambiguity. Don't make the assumption that conflicts are local to the rule where you observe the consequence.

Comment: @neomang: In fact, it was the `id: id symbol id` rule which was responsible. Updated the answer with an explanation.